# Write Unit Tests for RxSwift

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing, rx-swift

I got this class which I'd like to write tests for:

```
import CoreLocation
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

struct LocationManager {

    private (set) var authorized: Driver<Bool>
    private let coreLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    init() {
        coreLocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        coreLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

        authorized = Observable.deferred { [weak coreLocationManager] in
            let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            guard let coreLocManager = coreLocationManager else {
                return Observable.just(status)
            }
            return coreLocManager
                .rx_didChangeAuthorizationStatus
                .startWith(status)
            }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
            .map {
                switch $0 {
                case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
                    return true
                default:
                    return false
                }
        }

        coreLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Basically I want to test whether the authorized `Driver` has the correct value based on possible `CLAuthorizationStatuses`. I need a hint in the right direction since I am not familiar with unit testing with RxSwift. I guess my best option is to create a mock of `CLLocationManager` which returns some CLAuthorizationStatus when `authorizationStatus()` is called and afterwards I would check the value of the authorized `Driver` right ?

Any explanation on how to test this `LocationManager` class is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OK I got it working. However I am not sure if this is a valid solution. Feel free to correct me here.

First of all I **changed my LocationManager** class to this:

```
import CoreLocation
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

struct LocationManager<T where T: LocationManagerProtocol> {

    private (set) var authorized: Driver<Bool>
    private let coreLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    init(type: T.Type) {
        coreLocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        coreLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

        authorized = Observable.deferred { [weak coreLocationManager] in
            let status = type.authorizationStatus()
            guard let coreLocManager = coreLocationManager else {
                return Observable.just(status)
            }
            return coreLocManager
                .rx_didChangeAuthorizationStatus
                .startWith(status)
            }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
            .map {
                switch $0 {
                case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
                    return true
                default:
                    return false
                }
        }

        coreLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Basically it is possible now to provide a type conforming to a new protocol I wrote **`LocationManagerProtocol`**.

**Next the protocol implements the `authorizationStatus` function so I can mock this one.**

```
protocol LocationManagerProtocol {
    static func authorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus
}
```

Then I created an **extension to CLLocationManager** to implement this protocol:

```
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationManager: LocationManagerProtocol {

}
```

**Call from production code:** `let locationManager = LocationManager(type: CLLocationManager.self)`

**Call from test code:** `let locationManager = LocationManager(type: AuthorizedLocationManager.self)`
or `let locationManager = LocationManager(type: ForbiddenLocationManager.self)`

In my test class I added these two classes two **override the authorizationStatus method**:

```
class AuthorizedLocationManager: LocationManagerProtocol {
    static func authorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus {
        return .AuthorizedWhenInUse
    }
}

class ForbiddenLocationManager: LocationManagerProtocol {
    static func authorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus {
        return .Denied
    }
}
```

**My test cases:**

```
func testLocationAuthorizationPermitted() {
    let locationManager = LocationManager(type:  AuthorizedLocationManager.self)

    locationManager.authorized
    .driveNext { authorized in
        XCTAssertTrue(authorized)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}

func testLocationAuthorizationRejected() {
    let locationManager = LocationManager(type: ForbiddenLocationManager.self)

    locationManager.authorized
        .driveNext { authorized in
            XCTAssertFalse(authorized)
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Sorry for the long post. I thought I would give you all information on how I solved this now. However as I stated earlier I am new to this and would love to hear other opinions on this approach and whether this is a valid test scenario or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how `RxSwift` implements unit tests: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/4b3056b81f619c0bf12c6ee4e571582219e2b88d/Tests/RxSwiftTests/Tests/Observable%2BSingleTest.swift

As for using a mock of `CLLocationManager`, yea, dependency injection would be the way to go.